# How to remove every sequence of "()" in a string in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove every sequence of () in my string.
For example my String is:

```
String a = "() a)";
```

And I want it to become
" a)"

When I tried this it gave me an infinite loop

```
    public static String removeParentheses(String s) {
        while (s.contains("()")) {
            s = s.replaceAll("()", "");
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("\\(\\)", "");`

Answer (score 3):

String replaceAll method require regexp in parameter. In your case you provide empty group. To use string as parameter you can use replace method like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String toChange = "asa()assaa()ass()asa()";
        String result = toChange.replace("()", "");
        assert Objects.equals(result, "asaassaaassasax");
}
```

Or change the regexp to correct form using \ character in way:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String toChange = "asa()assaa()ass()asa()";
     String result = toChange.replaceAll("\\(\\)", "");
     assert Objects.equals(result, "asaassaaassasax");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According [the documentation of `String.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), the first argument is a regular expression.

This means `()` is not being treated literally, it's being treated as an empty [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), which effectively matches nothing. I think what you're looking for is the normal [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method. I'm aware that the names of these methods seem to imply that `replace` only replaces one instance while `replaceAll` replaces all of them, but this is not the case.

```java
public static String removeParentheses(String s) {
    return s.replace("()", "");
}
```

[JDoodle deomonstrating code above](https://jdoodle.com/ia/BNp)

If for some reason you would like to continue using `replaceAll` instead, you can dynamically escape the pattern using [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)).

```java
public static String removeParentheses(String s) {
    String pattern = Pattern.quote("()");
    return s.replaceAll(pattern, "");
}
```

[JDoodle demonstrating code above](https://jdoodle.com/ia/BNq)